# React Native - Gifted Chat messages issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I am using *react-native-gifted-chat* version "^0.16.3" but every time a new message comes it only updates last 2 messages. What can I do to update complete chat list on new message and is this the right way to do?

```
<View style={{
                    backgroundColor: 'white',
                    padding: 10,
                    width: "85%",
                    borderRadius: 5,
                    shadowColor: '#000',
                    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
                    shadowOpacity: 0.4,
                    shadowRadius: 1,
                    elevation: 5
                }}>
                    {/* <Text color={'black'} bold size={'4.4%'} style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }} >Client wants to hire you</Text> */}
                    <Bubble
                        {...item}
                        allowFontScaling={false}
                        wrapperStyle={{
                            right: {
                                backgroundColor: Theme.darkSkyBlue,
                                width:'100%'
                            },
                            left: {
                                backgroundColor: Theme.white,
                                width:'100%'
                            }
                        }}
                    />
                    { !answered && type === "button" && (
                        <Row style={{width:'100%'}}>
                            <Btn style={{width:'48%'}} onPress={() => requestOpportunities(State.TrainerHire, requestId, _id)} yes>
                                <Btn.Text allowFontScaling = {false}>YES</Btn.Text>
                            </Btn>
                            <Btn style={{width:'48%'}} activeOpacity={0.3} onPress={() => requestOpportunities(State.TrainerAccept, requestId, _id)} packages>
                                <Btn.Text color={'blue'} allowFontScaling = {false}>NO</Btn.Text>
                            </Btn>
                        </Row>
                    )}
                </View>
```

This is my code, when user click on yes or no button it should hide these buttons. It's working when its the last message but if there are some messages after this message it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it work around, I put a loader on screen and update the whole using API.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).